# how to check if a record exist in a database before inserting with php

Tags: php

I am creating a form that collects data and sends to a database using php, with a code snippet i got online.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","famakin","k");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo"FailedtoconnecttoMySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="INSERT INTO transactions(Username,Insured_Name,combined,Residential_Address,Telephone,Email,Make_Of_Car,Model,Engine_Number,Year_Of_Manufacture,Chassis_Number,Vehicle_Class,Colour,Registeration_Number,Product_Type,Premium,Policy_Number,Start_Date,Expiry_Date,Date_Begin,Type_Of_Insurance,Status,  Transaction_id)VALUES('$_POST[Username]','$_POST[Insured_Name]','$_POST[combined]','$_POST[Residential_Address]','$_POST[Telephone]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Make_Of_Car]','$_POST[Model]','$_POST[Engine_Number]','$_POST[Year_Of_Manufacture]','$_POST[Chassis_Number]','$_POST[Vehicle_Class]','$_POST[Colour]','$_POST[Registeration_Number]','$_POST[Product_Type]','$_POST[Premium]','$_POST[Policy_Number]','$_POST[Date]','$_POST[Date_Expiry]','$_POST[Date_Begin]','$_POST[Type_Of_Insurance]','$_POST[Status]','$_POST[Transaction_id]')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   die('Error:'.mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

This works for inserting details into the database,but i want to check if for example the username in which i am inserting into the database exists,please how do i go about this with what i have already?

regards

Comment: You should read up on slq injection and prepared statements.

Comment: If you make the username in the table unique.. Then the value won't get inserted..

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What did Google say when you put in "check if user exists in database"?

Comment: u need ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if user already exists in MySQL with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465468/how-to-check-if-user-already-exists-in-mysql-with-php)

Answer (score 4):

There are two main approaches, essentially...

1. `SELECT` from the database before trying to `INSERT`.  If the record is found by the `SELECT`, don't perform the `INSERT` and instead respond to the user accordingly.
2. Place [a `UNIQUE` constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) on the column (or set of columns) which needs to be unique in the table.  This would cause the `INSERT` to fail, and the code would have to catch and handle that failure and respond to the user accordingly.

The second option puts the responsibility squarely on the database itself, which is important if anything else if ever going to use that database and needs to maintain that same responsibility.

Also, ***and this is important***, please note that your code is open to SQL injection attacks, which allows users to *execute their own code* on your server.  You'll want to [read up on that so you can protect your application](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 4):

Here, you can do it via [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Username']);
$check_select = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE Username = '$username'"); 

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($check_select);

if($numrows > 0){

// do something

}

else{

// do something else

}
```

---

Although there are other ways to do this, it is but one example.

You can avoid this by also setting your column(s) as UNIQUE.

---

- By the way, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
  Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they much safer*.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a SELECT query before the INSERT.  If a record with that username exists then don't insert the record.

Comment: how do i go abt that, am a newbie please

Comment: @stackstack `select count(*) from Transactions.... where Username =..`.

Comment: can u be so kind to do an example with the code i have provided

Answer (score 1):

Well before you insert one you want to query for it's existence (please refer to Google on how to "[Select data from Database PHP](https://www.google.gg/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Select%20data%20from%20Database%20PHP)").

If that `select count(*) from Transactions.... where Username =..` returns something other than `0` the username is already taken.

Note: I have bigger concerns about the fact you include `POST`-Parameters directly into your SQL-Query string and recommend you read something about "[SQL Injection PHP](https://www.google.gg/?gws_rd=ssl#q=SQL%20Injection%20PHP)".