# PHP + MYSQL on Duplicate KEY still increase the INDEX KEY

Tags: php, mysql

My table have this style:

```
ID - EMAIL - VERSION - LASTUPDATE
```

where id = is auto increment and Primary:

and email is UNIQUE

so everytime someone use my Application it get the user Email and try to insert, if the email already exist, it UPDATE the row to new values for $version and $lastupdate

it almostly works 100%, its already updating the row perfectly, the problem is that when it do the UPDATE, still increase the auto increment id, so the next INSERT will not be the lastID plus one, and will be another number example:

```
ID - EMAIL - VERSION - LASTUPDATE
-----------------------------------
1 - test1@... - 1.0 - currentTime();
```

if the test2 load my app it will add and the database will be:

```
ID - EMAIL - VERSION - LASTUPDATE
-----------------------------------
1 - test1@.. - 1.0 - currentTime();
2 - test2@.. - 1.0 - currentTime();
```

so imagine now that the test2 has the new version and it update to this:

```
ID - EMAIL - VERSION - LASTUPDATE
-----------------------------------
1 - test1@.. - 1.1 - currentTime();
2 - test2@.. - 1.0 - currentTime();
```

perfectly isnt it? so the problem start when the test3 open my app, the id will not be 3, it will be 4 because the update added 1 more to the id(i dont know why)

```
ID - EMAIL - VERSION - LASTUPDATE
-----------------------------------
1 - test1@.. - 1.1 - currentTime();
2 - test2@.. - 1.0 - currentTime();
4 - test3@.. - 1.1 - currentTime();
```

why its increasing the plus one to the ID when do the update? i dont want it =(

my sql syntax:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `backups`.`regs` (`email`, `version`, `lastupdate`) VALUES ('$email', '$version', '$lastupdate')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE version='$version', lastupdate='$lastupdate'";
```

Comment: You can accomplish that by using transaction

Comment: @BranimirĐurek any tutorial please? i have no idea how

Comment: here is a simple php example of using transaction http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_commit.asp. Basically, transaction is something like IF state. If all queries were successfully executed, then commit that changes, but if one of your queries fail, then do nothing :)

Comment: i would love to see the create table and test this. that is bizarre

Comment: I remember now how not bizarre this issue was, @BK435

Comment: If a duplicate entry is "hit", the auto_increment will be wasted. Not for the **current** record, its auto_increment will remain the same. You will have gaps due to this, meaning if your auto_increment value for record was 1, if you inserted and went to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part, the number 2 will be used, will be discarded - and that's just perfectly normal, you shouldn't "defend" against it and just leave it be. There are reasons why it works like that, if you touch anything - kiss your integrity, performance and durability good bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok yeah, now I remember this issue. There was a guy once that wanted to do inserts, but each insert had to be in increments of `100` if you could imagine, starting @1000. And we had to wrap the whole thing in a stored proc to have one place of vulnerability. Your issue surfaced and it threw off his numbering by 1 or so.

By wrapping it, we could sanely have one point of doing it, with a lock, and maintain the auto_inc value with `ALTER TABLE`

The other approach I said to him was have an incrementer table, lock the 1 row,  get the value in that row, use it, update that incTable by 100. unlock.

The whole time we were laughing about OCD issues. I think he liked multiples of 10 only, idk

Edit:

### Schema:

```
-- drop table ocd_nextnums;
create table ocd_nextnums
(   -- id table for nextnum, for the OCD impaired
    tableName varchar(100) not null,
    nextnum int not null
    -- won't bother with indexes, go for it if you want
)engine=INNODB; -- note engine type

insert ocd_nextnums(tableName,nextnum) values('thing',1);
insert ocd_nextnums(tableName,nextnum) values('some_other_table',1);

-- drop table thing;
create table thing
(   id int primary key, -- NOT an auto_increment, but is a PK
    email varchar(100) not null,
    version varchar(20) not null,
    lastupdate datetime not null,
    UNIQUE KEY (email)
)engine=MyIsam;
```

### Stored Proc:

```
-- drop procedure putInThing;
delimiter $$
create procedure putInThing
(
    email_In varchar(100), version_In varchar(20)
)
BEGIN
    declare toUse int;
    declare theCount int;

    select count(*) into theCount from thing where email=email_In;
    select id into toUse from thing where email=email_In;   -- useful for result set @end
    IF theCount=1 THEN
        -- was there, do UPDATE
        update thing set version=version_In,lastupdate=now() where email=email_In;
    ELSE
        -- new row, do INSERT (please note the FOR UPDATE clause)
        select nextnum into toUse from ocd_nextnums where tableName='thing' FOR UPDATE;
        update ocd_nextnums set nextnum=nextnum+1 where tableName='thing';

        insert thing(id,email,version,lastupdate) values (toUse,email_In,version_In,now());
    end if;
    select toUse;   -- <------- that was your id
END
$$
```

### Test:

```
call putInThing('t1@t.com','111');
call putInThing('t2@t.com','121');
call putInThing('t3@t.com','107');
select * from thing;
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | email    | version | lastupdate          |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | t1@t.com | 111     | 2015-08-14 17:08:10 |
|  2 | t2@t.com | 121     | 2015-08-14 17:08:54 |
|  3 | t3@t.com | 107     | 2015-08-14 17:08:56 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+

call putInThing('t3@t.com','101111007'); -- is an update
call putInThing('t3@t.com','42'); -- is an update
call putInThing('t3@t.com','10007'); -- is an update
call putInThing('h@hillaryclinton.com','1'); -- is an insert

select * from thing;
+----+----------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | email                | version | lastupdate          |
+----+----------------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | t1@t.com             | 111     | 2015-08-14 17:08:10 |
|  2 | t2@t.com             | 121     | 2015-08-14 17:08:54 |
|  3 | t3@t.com             | 10007   | 2015-08-14 17:22:09 |
|  4 | h@hillaryclinton.com | 1       | 2015-08-14 17:22:47 |
+----+----------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

From the Mysql INNODB part of [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

> To implement reading and incrementing the counter, first perform a
>   locking read of the counter using FOR UPDATE, and then increment the
>   counter.....

Will you see me using this, probably not. Just showing it. I am fine with gaps and sleeping at night. Which is why I named the first table what I did :>

Comment: I got the message ^^! so the best way is to before insert check if it exist, if not insert, if exist = update row, isn't it? so I avoid the gaps and the OCD issues =P

Comment: marked as question because it teach me the way and the problems that I can cause, so I will prefer to first check if exist, if not insert, if exist update the row (I think doing this update out of the ON DUPLICATE will not increase the counter, since this is the normal behavior)

thx Drew

Comment: solved using this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465468/how-to-check-if-user-already-exists-in-mysql-with-php just added the UPDATE inside the IF ;) thank you again Drew

Comment: my pleasure. whatever you choose, hopefully it is safe !

Answer (score 2):

Fro what you describe you have the wrong value in $version before you carried out the insert. And that is populated in code you've not shown us.

You should be using the version number already held in the database:

```
INSERT INTO `backups`.`regs` 
(`email`, `version`, `lastupdate`) 
VALUES ('$email', 1, '$lastupdate')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE version=version+1, lastupdate='$lastupdate'"
```

Comment: I guess he misunderstood, I just guess

Answer (score 1):

Because you already passed the values, then you should use `version = VALUES(version), lastupdate = VALUES(lastupdate)` for `ON DUPLICATE`, Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `backups`.`regs` (`email`, `version`, `lastupdate`) VALUES ('$email', '$version', '$lastupdate')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE version = VALUES(version), lastupdate = VALUES(lastupdate)";
```

Comment: but i need to pass the values, if i do not pass how can it insert for new record?

Comment: you should pass them for insert, but don't need to pass again for `on duplicate`

Comment: @Drew I tested my approach, I don't know, maybe that way is fine too.

Comment: ok I will test it too, let ya know. Ok it gives a 1064 syntax error if you finish the statement with  `on duplicate key update;`   ..... if that is what you mean

Comment: this not solved the problem =( but thanks, it work like I was doing before