# How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some variable prefix

Tags: php, mysql

How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some variable prefix ??

I am trying to make auto increment field using trigger in which both string+number are variable.For example PRJ001, PRJ002, PRD001, PRD002...etc. 
How can I implement this either using trigger or using simple query ???

Any suggestion to make my day?

Comment: Store the string and number separately and don't use auto_increment. Despite its name, that's not what it's for.

Comment: Can this be done, sure. I would do it thru a stored proc, locking, spend 20 minutes, then wonder why it really mattered

Comment: Here is that [stored proc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32018207/1816093) I was referring to. It means your inserts happen thru a stored proc, not an insert statement natively. That issue over there was about how insert on duplicate update actually creates gaps in the auto_increment value. The stored proc could be tailored for your purposes. But don't. The concept is insane. Don't use it, tailor it, it will cause unnecessary insanity.

Answer (score 2):

Like it is said in the comments, you can't use autoincrement for this.

In your place I wouldn't use separate enumeration, but rather one for all: PRJ001, PRJ002, PRD003, PRD004, PRJ005 and so on.

After all it's just a name, without any significance in the number.

Comment: but after some insertion of 'PRJ' i want 'PRD' as a prefix. And there is also chance that after some 'PRD' insertion i want to insert with 'PRJ'.

Comment: And In this Condition is that Once new prefix are come you have to start your counter with 0

Comment: I agree with YCS. Don't get all OCD over your id numbers

Answer (score 2):

I do not think thats possible, The are two ways I know on how you could achieve this:

1. Use INT field and translate it to whatever you want when you read it.
2. make it a var charand insert it manually (do calculation on your code before adding to the database)